# Atualizando a estrutura de múltiplos bancos de dados no Azure

Tags: sql, microsoft-azure

Tenho 5 banco de dados SQL (*Web Edition*) no Azure que devem ser exatamente iguais quanto a estrutura (*`procedures`, `tabelas`, `views`, `triggers`,...*) mas os dados são diferentes.

Tem como atualizar a estrutura dos bancos de uma forma mais ágil, como se eles fossem um *mirror* de um banco master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri algo que resolve os meus problemas.
O SQL Server Management Studio 2008 possui uma funcionalidade chamada Registered Databases.
Após registrar os bancos de dados com suas respectivas credenciais, é possível executar um script em todos os bancos ao mesmo tempo.
Para isso:

1. Abra o MSSMS e conecte-se a um servidor qualquer, no meu caso é o servidor chamado "LOCALDB";
2. No "Pesquisador de Objetos" conecte-se a outros servidores. "WEBDB" no meu caso;
3. Clique com o botão direito do mouse em cima de um dos servidores e escolha a opção "Registrar";
4. Defina as credenciais e um nome qualquer para o servidor e clique em Salvar;
5. Faça o mesmo com os outros servidores;

Agora para executar scripts em todos ao mesmo tempo basta acessar Exibir > Servidores Registrados. Ou aperte Ctrl + Alt + G.
Expanda o "Mecanismo de Banco de Dados", clique com o botão direito em "Local Server Groups" > "Nova Consulta".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que se houver mais de um servidor no "Local Server Groups" a barra de status da área de script ficará vermelha indicando que o comando será executado em nome de vários logons.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome dos bancos em ambos os servidores devem ser os mesmos e você deve utilizar o comando use, ou seja:

```
use meuBancodeDados
select * from minhaTB
```

meuBancodeDados deve existir nos 2 servidores ou será executado apenas naquele que existe.

Para mais informações:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode criar um project database no Visual Studio, ou usar o SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools).

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPll3dMxTXU

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Thiago.

Comment: Olá Thiago. Descobri algo melhor. Veja minha resposta.